# How does KDB decimal tolerance affect the `in` operator?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a range:

```
a: (0.005*til 13) - 0.03
-0.03 -0.025 -0.02 -0.015 -0.01 -0.005 0 0.005 0.01 0.015 0.02 0.025 0.03
```

When I do `-0.01 in a` I get `0b`, which I wasn't expecting. When I do `-0.015 in a` I get `1b`.

Even more curiously, when I index directly:

```
-0.01 = a 4
```

I get `1b`.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `in` keyword does not use comparison tolerance (wiggle room) when checking for list membership (see [https://code.kx.com/q/basics/precision/#:~:text=distinct%20except%20group%20in%20inter%20union%20xgroup](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/precision/#:%7E:text=distinct%20except%20group%20in%20inter%20union%20xgroup)).

You can see that the same problem doesn't arise when `a` is defined as so:

```
q)a:-0.03 -0.025 -0.02 -0.015 -0.01 -0.005 0 0.005 0.01 0.015 0.02 0.025 0.03
q)-0.01 in a
1b
```

The list `a` generated in the way you provide gives an element that isn't precisely `-0.01` and this is why `in` returns `0b`:

```
q)a: (0.005*til 13) - 0.03
q)-0.01 - a 4
-1.734723e-018
```

Answer (score 4):

This page details what does and doesn't use comparison tolerance: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/precision/#use

In general you should never need to check for "float equals" or "float in", it almost always ends in trouble! If you must, use some closeness measure.